# Calling countDownTimer

Tags: android, methods, kotlin

How i can call my CountDownTimer in onResume()?

```
private fun countDownTime(timeOut: Long) {
    object : CountDownTimer(timeOut, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            actionWarning.text = "Please wait: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: call your method countDownTime(1000) in method onResume() or what u mean?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to extract your `CountDownTimer` to a field:

```
class YourClass {

    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(timeOut, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                actionWarning.text = "Please wait: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }
            override fun onFinish() {
            }
        }

    private fun countDownTime(timeOut: Long) {
      timer.start()
    }

    fun onResume() {
      timer.whatever()
    }
}
```